# Need Help | UnitTest | Kafka custom ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with Custom Record FilterStrategy

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-kafka

Trying to unit test, ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with custom RecordFilterStrategy, however not able to find optimal approach to test the filter strategy.

```
  class ConsumerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> messageListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> consumerRecord.value().getType().contains("MYFILTER"));
    return factory;
  }

}
```

**Unit Test**

```
  @Mock
  KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
  ConsumerConfiguration configuration;
  @Test
  void testMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> actual =
        configuration.messageListenerContainerFactory();
    assertEquals(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
        actual.getContainerProperties().getKafkaConsumerProperties());
  }
```

Though this code is good for unit testing, however does not provides the code coverge for Custom RecordFilterStrategy i.e. lambda function, so need help if some one have already done unittest/code coverage for Kafka Listener Container Factory and what is the best approach for handling.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure unit test of the factory configuration, where the filter is

```
record -> record.value().contains("foo")
```

you can do something like this...

```java
@SpringBootTest
class So63239177ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    private int called;

    @Test
    void testFilter() throws Exception {
        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        endpoint.setBean(this);
        endpoint.setMethod(getClass().getDeclaredMethod("listen", ConsumerRecord.class));
        endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());
        endpoint.setTopics("foo");
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createListenerContainer(endpoint);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MessageListener<String, String> messageListener =
                (MessageListener<String, String>) container.getContainerProperties().getMessageListener();
        messageListener.onMessage(new ConsumerRecord<>("foo", 0, 0L, null, "foo"));
        assertThat(this.called).isEqualTo(0);
        messageListener.onMessage(new ConsumerRecord<>("foo", 0, 0L, null, "bar"));
        assertThat(this.called).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> in) {
        this.called++;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a slightly simpler (and perhaps cleaner) way to do it...

```java
@SpringBootTest
class So632391771ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor<?, ?> bpp;

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Test
    void testFilter() throws Exception {
        TestListener listener = new TestListener();
        this.bpp.postProcessAfterInitialization(listener, "test");
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = registry.getListenerContainer("test")
                .getContainerProperties();
        assertThat(containerProperties.getGroupId()).isEqualTo("test");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MessageListener<String, String> messageListener =
                    (MessageListener<String, String>) containerProperties.getMessageListener();
        messageListener.onMessage(new ConsumerRecord<>("foo", 0, 0L, null, "foo"));
        assertThat(listener.called).isEqualTo(0);
        messageListener.onMessage(new ConsumerRecord<>("foo", 0, 0L, null, "bar"));
        assertThat(listener.called).isEqualTo(1);
    }

}

class TestListener { // NOTE: Not a @Bean

    int called;

    @KafkaListener(id = "test", topics = "foo", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(String in) {
        this.called++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gary, it helped!

Comment: I added another way to do it; perhaps easier.

Comment: @Garry, one more question off the topic, not sure, if its okay to ask in same thread, i want to seek my consumer to specific offset, what is the best approach to handle it in Spring-Kafka.

Comment: You should not ask supplemental questions in comments - it doesn't help people find questions and answers. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek) if you have further questions on this issue, ask a new question.